# Sorting in html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

This code grabs information from yaml files and outputs them in ascending order (I'm assuming by default). I can't figure out how to code this to reverse the order. Any suggestions? The site is using Middleman and ERB as templating language.

**View:**

```
<ul class="app-list">
  <% data.apps.each do |app| %>
    <% if app[1][:categories][:featured] && app[1][:categories][:script] %>
      <li>
        <%= partial 'partials/app', locals: { app: app[1] } %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<ul class="app-list">
  <% data.apps.reverse.each do |app| %>
    <% if app[1][:categories][:featured] && app[1][:categories][:script] %>
      <li>
        <%= partial 'partials/app', locals: { app: app[1] } %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. Inside the template is another set of code that display the data in non-alphabetical form. Maybe I need to declare some variables structured like this? http://pastebin.com/pi2y3Cw1

Comment: @billpixby, can you possibly provide some dummy yaml that I can look at to understand better? or whatever the `data` variable looks like